# Rsnaphost "works" when tested but not when run

Tags: backup, cifs, rsnapshot

I have set up rsnapshot successfully a couple of times, and maybe because everything was rather painless (except for the vi tab fiasco of 2013) I am now out of ideas.

I have a cifs mounted remote drive at say `\BACKUP` and rsnapshot configured to copy the selected files to this folder with `no_create_root  1`. 
If I run the configtest, `rsnapshot configtest` I get a `Syntax OK` message. I have also done the `rsnapshot -t weekly` test and I get no errors.

At this point, I have no reason to believe that things are not working, so I just run `rsnapshot weekly`, which is when I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these options:
/usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Could not mkpath("/BACKUP/weekly.0/", 0, 0755);
```

Permissions are definitely set correctly, I can create folders and rsnapshot can also create folders (I have tested this by having rsnapshot dump the log file into the `/BACKUP` successfully).